# "Universal" versus "nonuniversal" in the topological entanglement entropy

Tags: condensed-matter, entropy, topological-order

In their [seminal paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510092), Kitaev and Preskill consider a 2D area law for entanglement of the form

$$
S(\rho) = \alpha |\partial A| - \gamma + \cdots.
$$

Here $\rho$ denotes the density matrix associated with the ground state of the system within a circular region $A$, $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are constants, $|\partial A|$ is the circumference of the circle, and $\cdots$ represents corrections that vanish as the circular region is taken to be large.

Preskill and Kitaev describe $\alpha$ as "nonuniversal and ultraviolet divergent" and $\gamma$ is a "universal additive constant characterizing a global feature of the entanglement in the ground state". They then go on to detail different systems which have *different values* of $\gamma$.

I am confused in one what sense $\alpha$ is nonuniversal and $\gamma$ is. Both constants take different values for different systems. The constant $\gamma$ is more robust and has more physical meaning as it is a topological invariant, related to the total quantum dimension. However, I still find this distinction between "universal" and "nonuniversal" to be puzzling as both values are system-dependent. In what sense are these words being used in this context?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that $\gamma$ is constant throughout a phase - i.e., it can only change at a phase transition, i.e. when the gap closes. Thus, it can be used as a signature of the phase - in this sense, it is universal.

On the other hand,  $\alpha$ will vary continuously throughout the phase and can take any possible value, and it will also not be robust against local perturbations. In particular, this means it cannot be used as a signature to identify a phase (since it can take any value in any phase). (Of course, this does not mean it is completely useless - on the contrary, it quantifies the amount of entanglement per unit volume in the state.)

Maybe the most clear way to see this is to check what happens to $S(\rho)$ when you rescale, i.e., renormalize, the system: Under rescaling by a factor $\lambda$, $\alpha\mapsto\lambda \alpha$, while $\gamma$ will not change.